# Laravel RESTFUL find function receives id and its looking for "id" I want it different

Tags: database, laravel

im using restful functions with uuid. The method `Model::find($id)` receives the id and it looks for "id" column name, but in my db table the `id` names its `idResource`, how can I change or look for that name in my table columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood you correctly, you want to use [eloquent-sluggable](https://github.com/cviebrock/eloquent-sluggable) package.

It adds some methods like `findBySlug()`.

Or you can just use something like:

```
$data = SomeData::where('id', 'idResource')->get();
```

Comment: YEAH!! It worked, thanks!!! I just had to add ->get(), just like this  $data = SomeData::where('idResource', $id)->get();  Thank you so much!!